# Absolute paths for resources in LESS CSS with ASP.net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I know there are other questions, but none have the answer I need.

Just need to be able to force an **absolute** path in some LESS that's included in an MVC page so that the images (etc) are correctly picked up.

```
[websiteroot]
----Content
--------img
------------<image files>
--------bootstrap
------------<bootstrap files>
--------site.LESS
--------Site_styles.LESS
----Views
--------Shared
------------_Layout.cshtml
```

It's not even in a bundle, it's just directly included in _Layout.cshtml as

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/Site_styles.less");
```

In Site_styles.less I have

```
.carousel-image-1
{
    width: 100%;
    background: url('img/banner1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

but I can't get it to be absolute, i.e.

```
"~/Content/img/banner1.jpg"
```

it is rendered as

```
background: url('/Content/img/sodexo_banner1.jpg')
```

---

In case it matters, other LESS [bootstrap etc] **is** in a bundle like so

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

```
    bundles.UseCdn = true;
    var cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
    var jsTransformer = new JsTransformer();
    var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

    var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/css");
    cssBundle.Include("~/Content/Site.less");
    cssBundle.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less");

    //cssBundle.Include("~/Content/Site_variables.less");
    cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
    cssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
    bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CssRewriteUrlTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

From docs:

> Rewrites urls to be absolute so assets will still be found after bundling.

**Example**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
        .Include("~/Content/Site.less")
        .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Comment: I did - and it made no difference - probably because my Site_styles.less script is **NOT** bundled. As mentioned above. But gimme a sec and I WILL include it in the bundle then try CssRewriteUrlTransform...

Comment: Nope, putting in  cssBundle.Include("~/Content/Site_styles.less", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
still gives  background: url('/Content/img/banner1.jpg')